# Aligned memory allocated by _align_malloc is not freed by _aligned_free function

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, malloc, delete-operator

int main()
{

1. int *aligned;

   // aligned value 0xcccccccc{???}
2. aligned = (int*)_aligned_malloc(sizeof(int) * 1000, 16);

   // aligned value **0x001d9490**{-842150451}
3. _aligned_free(aligned);

   //// aligned value **0x001d9490**{-17891602} address did not change
4. *aligned == 100;
5. int *y;

   // y value 0xcccccccc{???}
6. y  = new int();

   // y value **0x001d9480**{0}
7. delete(y);

   // y value **0x00008123**{???}  address has changed
8. *y = 100; // Gives exception

}

My question:

Why code at line 4 does not give exception? Does it mean memory is not properly freed by _aligned_free? If yes, then how should we free memory allocated by _aligned_malloc.

Comment: In cases 1 and 5, you are reading an uninitialized value, that's a bug. In cases 4 and 8, you are reading from memory you freed, that's a bug. The generic answer to "why doesn't code that has a bug in it do what I expect" is "that's why we fix bugs, code with bugs doesn't do what you expect, fix the bug and the code will do what you expect".

Comment: Thanks David. I got your point that these are the bugs which should be fixed. My intention for this question was why memory pointed by aligned ( after _aligned_free) is not set to invalid memory whereas in case of y ( after delete) it is. It looks to me (after reading comments) more kind of compiler or heap deallocator thing. I just wanted to confirm that. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

The code at line 4 isn't doing anything - you are using `==` (test for equality) not `=` (assignment) on that line.  Well, actually, it *is* doing something - it will attempt to *read* from an address in a memory block you just freed (and compare that value to 100).  This might not necessarily cause an exception - many heap managers will carve chunks out of larger blocks allocated in your process address space, so freeing one might very well just mark the block as available for the heap manager to reuse.  Reading/writing to this space after freeing might not cause an exception every time (because it might still be part of the valid heap space for the process), but it is definitely an error.

Also, after calling `_aligned_free` the pointer value (`aligned`) shouldn't change - that doesn't mean the memory was not freed.

Comment: Thanks Frasnian. I got the point that memory will always be freed by _aligned_free if there are no exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

> int *aligned;
>
> // aligned value 0xcccccccc{???}

You did not initialize the pointer, so it's got whatever garbage value was there before `main` started. Do `int *aligned = NULL;` if you want it to start off null.

> aligned = (int*)_aligned_malloc(sizeof(int) * 1000, 16);
>
> // aligned value 0x001d9490{-842150451}

Looks OK

> _aligned_free(aligned);
>
> //// aligned value 0x001d9490{-17891602} address did not change

None of the `free` calls changes the pointer passed in. Ever.

> *aligned == 100;

As frasnian pointed out, this does a comparison and throws the result away. But even if you changed that to an assignment, you're dereferencing a freed pointer, which is undefined behavior. And that means anything could happen: it could work, it could crash, it could do something else unexpected.

> int *y;
>
> // y value 0xcccccccc{???}

Again, uninitialized.

> y = new int();
>
> // y value 0x001d9480{0}

Okay, you have a pointer to an `int`.

> delete(y);
>
> // y value 0x00008123{???} address has changed

That's unexpected. Might be a feature of your compiler. Might be an optimization reusing the register.

> *y = 100; // Gives exception

Because you dereferenced a deleted pointer, and again you're in undefined behavior land. Apparently your platform does not like odd addresses for integers. Not all platforms throw exceptions here.

---

The rule is that a pointer that you have passed to `free` or `delete` is gone. Dead. An ex-pointer. Pushing up the bit-daisies. Pining for the fjords. It is no more.

There might be a value left over in the register, but it is no longer valid and should not be used. The compiler cannot be expected to catch the cases where you try to use a dead pointer.